# pyiceberg : 403 Forbidden Error with Glue Catalog

Tags: python, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

Caveat that I'm new to iceberg and working on a POC around it. I've created an Iceberg table in AWS Athena and am trying to connect to it via pyiceberg. I'm able to successfully connect to the catalog and get the namespaces / tables fine. However, when calling load_table or create table operations, I'm fed back with a 403 error. I have environment variables configured with my connection details, and doing the equivalent HEAD operations on the metadata files via boto3.client('s3') works fine.

Am I missing a configuration in the load_catalog block? Has anyone else resolved this error or have any insight into a fix?

```
catalog = catalog.load_catalog('glue', **{
        'type': 'glue'
    })

databases = catalog.list_namespaces()
for d in databases:
    print(d[0])
    tables = catalog.list_tables(d)

table = catalog.load_table('default.iceberg_test')
```

Error stacktrace:

```
FutureWarning: The S3RegionRedirector class has been deprecated for a new internal replacement. A future version of botocore may remove this class.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 112, in _error_wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 358, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dataenginerd/python/utilities/pyiceberg_test.py", line 36, in <module>
    table = catalog.load_table('default.iceberg_test')
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyiceberg/catalog/glue.py", line 278, in load_table
    return self._convert_glue_to_iceberg(load_table_response.get(PROP_GLUE_TABLE, {}))
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyiceberg/catalog/glue.py", line 180, in _convert_glue_to_iceberg
    metadata = FromInputFile.table_metadata(file)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyiceberg/serializers.py", line 56, in table_metadata
    with input_file.open() as input_stream:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyiceberg/io/fsspec.py", line 166, in open
    return self._fs.open(self.location, "rb")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1135, in open
    f = self._open(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 640, in _open
    return S3File(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1989, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1491, in __init__
    self.size = self.details["size"]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1504, in details
    self._details = self.fs.info(self.path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 114, in wrapper
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 99, in sync
    raise return_result
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 54, in _runner
    result[0] = await coro
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1210, in _info
    out = await self._call_s3(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 339, in _call_s3
    return await _error_wrapper(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 139, in _error_wrapper
    raise err
PermissionError: Forbidden
```

I've tried verifying the same operations with the boto3 stack work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem was that the s3fs dependency was not installed. I ran

```
pip install "pyiceberg[glue,s3fs,pyarrow]"
```

And that resolved the errors I had been seeing. Hopefully this helps any other folks in the same predicament in the future.